# Point to first element of a linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I hope you can help me, It's really important. Please
I have a program which I need to print a name 23 times char by char using linked lists.  I have made it work printing it once, even though I have a for loop I can't make it print the text 23 times. Please help. I don't know where to start.

You would really help me a lot by answering this question, I've tried a lot but im still not able to understand how to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct L {
    char c;
    struct L *next;
}List;

List *l = NULL; // list head, we'll prepend nodes here
int c;          // variable for current read character

List *getInput(void)
{
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {       // read until enter
        List *n = calloc(1, sizeof(List)); // create new list node
        n->c = c;     // store read character in that node
        n->next = l;  // prepend newly created node to our list
        l = n;        // store newly created node as head of list
    }
    return l;
}
int main ( void ) {
    printf("Ingresa tu nombre.\n");
    getInput();
    printf("\n");
    int i = 0;
    for(i;i<23;

        //I tried something like l=1; here bit it didn't work.

        while (l != NULL) { // while we have not reached end of list
            putchar(l->c);  // print character stored in list
            printf("\n");
            l = l->next;    // and advance to next list node
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the for loop, if the list has 23 nodes then the while loop will iterate 23 times.

Comment: I need that the code inside the while repeats 23 times, No matter how many nodes i have.

Comment: oh, well maybe move `printf("\n")` out of and after the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start at the beginning of the list each time through the `for` loop. This means you must not overwrite the the variable `l` that points to the beginning of the list. Instead, use a different variable for iterating.

```
int main ( void ) {
    printf("Ingresa tu nombre.\n");
    getInput();
    printf("\n");
    int i = 0;
    for(i;i<23;i++){
        List *cur = l;
        while (cur != NULL) { // while we have not reached end of list
            putchar(cur->c);  // print character stored in list
            printf("\n");
            cur = cur->next;    // and advance to next list node
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It was just what I needed. You saved me, Literally.